# React Native app so slow when components are nested in each other

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks

My problem occurs when I try to implement the below structure.
Main screen will be bottom tabs, and the app has a few more full screen overlay, for simplicity, it will only be used in TabOne.

[image]

So the structure for my tabs would be like this:

```
<Tab.Navigator
        initialRouteName={MenuType.TAB_ONE}
        screenOptions={{ headerShown: false }}
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        tabBar={(props) => <BottomTabs {...props} />}
      >
        <Tab.Screen
          name={MenuType.TAB_ONE}
          component={TabOne}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name={MenuType.TAB_TWO}
          component={TabTwo}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name={MenuType.TAB_THREE}
          component={TabThree}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
```

The `<BottomTabs {...props} />` is my own custom bottomtab UI.
And if I put all my `MyOverlay` components inside `TabOne`, then it just won't  cover bottom tabs.

[image]

It'll work as I expected if I put them at the same level with the `Tab.Navigator` within my main app, let's call it `MainApp` :

```
<Tab.Navigator .....>
<MyOverlay />
```

But as they are on different component. I used `useContext` to communicate with each others.

For example, when a button in the TabOne page is pressed, I will call the context method to `setFlag()` the `openBottomSheet` flag, then I will `useContext` to listen to `openBottomSheet` flag in my `MainApp`.

But as the state changes, `MainApp` just rerender everything. which means it rerender my custom `BottomTabs`, all `TabOne`,`TabTwo`, `TabThree`, and in each Tab page, there's a punch of child components. My app just get slower and slower when more components are added into the views. (I can't imagine what would happen if there is a state (lies in `MainApp` as my dialog is in the overlay which is located there) that track changes within the dialog, then my app just like 'restart' on every input I type in the dialog...)

I feel like I run the whole app again on every state changes.

I tried to use `React.memo` for some stable component, like `BottomTabs` but no luck as all my components have their own states, contexts,... as stated here https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

I tried to make my component a class that extends `React.Component` but then my `useContext` won't work inside `React.Component`

I don't know what is wrong with my usage of Hooks...

Thank you for your time.

**UPDATE**:
A reproducible example repo https://github.com/tranhoainam/test-tabs-and-sheet
Everytime I click a button (show sheet, or show/hide dialog) I'll get these logs:

```
>>> RENDER MAIN APP
>>>->>> RENDER one
>>>->>> RENDER two
>>>->>> RENDER three
   -->>> RENDER OVERLAY
```

My app slows so much as the components are very complex

**UPDATE 2**
My first guess is that because my app is currently wrapped within the `<MainProvider>`, so once every part of the state of that provide changes, RN will rerender the whole child of that Provider.

So I came up with a solution which is create another Provider just for the overlay, called `OverlayProvider`.

- Then I wrap the `<Overlays/>` inside that `<OverlayProvider>`
- Then I have to wrap the button that call the sheet with my new `<OverlayProvider>` otherwise an error will comes up saying that my `openBottomSheet` method is undefined.

This is when another problem came up. Because there're two `<OverlayProvider>` so looks like those are two different instances, so when `openBottomSheet` is called. The flag within the `<Overlays/>` doesn't change.

Is there a way I can make those two provider one instance?

Please check out my solution branch here to get the idea https://github.com/tranhoainam/test-tabs-and-sheet/tree/another-solution

Comment: Can you update your question to include all relevant code you've an issue with? See [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). If possible, could you create a *running* [Expo snack](https://expo.dev/) of your code that reproduces the issue we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: Hi @DrewReese please check the updated repo at the bottom to see if you can have a better guess on what's happening. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using Redux for my case. Context is not suitable for my case.